# Vertical navigation with sub menus with image up and down links for each level with active link highlight when on selected page

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I have the following css vertical navigation menu I have done. There are up and down images for the parent category 30px high for rollover and separate up and down images for the second and third levels of the menu rollover at 25px high.

For each level, there is a different type of up and down images if there is no continuing category.

It works OK except for 3 areas that I have been struggling with for days now and can't seem to see where I have gone wrong.

The first is that the text for each level gets smaller and smaller for some reason and the second is that at the third level, all the images shown the up and down images as if there it a continuing category, and last but not least, when a category is selected in the first, second or third category, I can't seem to find a way to keep those links highlighted to show the user that they are in that area.

I hope someone is able to figure this out as I have been going crazy for days now. Thanks in advance.

Please find the current code below (in the image areas I have described what the images are for to understand what images I am using) :

**The HTML:**

```
        <div id="nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
                            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#nav {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    z-index:1;
}
#nav ul.menu, #nav ul.menu > ul.sub-menu, #nav ul.menu > ul.sub-sub-menu {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul.menu > li {
    float: left;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    line-height:2.2em;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

#nav ul.menu ul.sub-menu > li , #nav ul.menu ul.sub-sub-menu > li {
    float: left;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    font-size:0.7em;
    line-height:2.2em;
}

#nav li a {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#nav ul.menu > li > a {
    background: transparent url('../../parent-category-with-submenus.png');
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

#nav ul.sub-menu > li > a, #nav ul.sub-sub-menu > li {
    background: transparent url('../../second-third-categories-with-submenus.png');
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

#nav ul.sub-menu > li:hover > a:only-child, #nav ul.sub-sub-menu > li:hover > a {
    background: transparent url('../../second-third-categories-with-NO-submenus-ROLLOVER.png');
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

#nav ul.menu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav li > ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:192px;
}
#nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu  {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:-40px;
    margin-left:198px;
}
#nav li:hover > ul.sub-sub-menu  {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:198px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Font Size**

You font size gets smaller because you are using `em`s.  An `em` is a relative unit.  If you're base font size is `20px` and you're using `0.75em` then the font size of a child element whose parent used the base 20px font size would be `15px` (20x0.75=15).  Now a child of that child (grandchild) would start with the child's font size of `15px` and it's font size would be `11.25px` (15x0.75=11.25).  I set the text to be 16px for all `li` in the jsFiddle below.

**UP and DOWN images**

I didn't bother figuring out the exact issue with this but you do have a lot of kruft in this part of your *CSS*.  I would add a class to the `li` that has a sub-menu within it.  Something like `.has-sub-menu`.  Then target the anchor tags like so `.menu > .has-sub-menu > a` and `.sub-menu > .has-sub-menu > a`.  Also see the jsFiddle below.

*HTML*

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-sub-menu">
            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/" title="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
.menu > .has-sub-menu > a {
     background-image: url(img-one.png);
}
.sub-menu > .has-sub-menu > a {
     background-image: url(img-two.png);
}
```

**Navigation Highlighting**

This one cannot be done with CSS unless you add a class to each `li` or anchor tag.  Something along the lines of the name of the page and then on each page add a body class of the same or similar name.

*HTML*

```html
<!-- your code -->
<body class="products">
     <!-- more of your code -->
     <div id="nav">
          <ul class="menu">
               <li class="products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
               <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
               <!-- more links -->
          </ul>
          <!-- more links -->
     </div>
     <!-- more of your code -->
</body>
```

In the example above we are viewing the `products` page.  For the `about` page you would replace the class on the body tag with `about`.  In the end this does not have to be added to the body tag but some other ancestor element.  But the body tag is a nice clean solution and helps ensure that the class will be encapsulated within one another.

Then you could target the link like so with your CSS.

*CSS*

```css
/* non-active */
#nav li {
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
}

/* active */
.products .products,
.about .about {
     color: red;
     background-color: blue;
}
```

If the above is not doeable then I believe you will have to do some light programming via PHP, ASP or whatever server side language you have available to you.  You could also use JavaScript.  You can also find answers to this with a simple StackOverflow search.

The fiddle below addresses all three issues with the solutions above.  I also added a little jQuery so you can switch out and try the navigation highlighting.

http://jsfiddle.net/u2V8v/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Part 1 about font size is correct. I usually use "px" but swapped to "em" accidentally without making the next menu inherent. Thanks for that. As for the up and down images area, if you read you will see I have already done this in the script I uploaded. The answer to this is below under "Issue #2" by @koala_dev. For the third part, the way you say is how I was going to do it but the problem comes when I have to keep active the highlight for the second and third sub-menus. But the idea is sound, thank you. You got 2 out of 3 so the answer mark goes to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1:** The text gets smaller in the sub-menus because you have this rule

```
#nav ul.menu ul.sub-menu > li , #nav ul.menu ul.sub-sub-menu > li {
    ...
    font-size:0.7em;
    ...
}
```

while the default for the first level items is

```
#nav ul.menu > li {
    ...
    font-size:0.9em;
    ...
}
```

Either remove the font-size decalaration for the submenus or set the value to `inherit`

**Issue #2**

I couldn't test this since I don't have your images so I'm not sure if this is what's causing the problem but it seems you're missing the `> a` at the end of this CSS rule selector

```
#nav ul.sub-menu > li > a, #nav ul.sub-sub-menu > li {
    background: transparent url('../../second-third-categories-with-submenus.png');
    ...
}
```

**Issue #3**

To highlight the menu items you can just set a background color on the hover state, they will stay highlighted while the user is browsing sub-menus

```
#nav ul li:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Your Issue #1 answer is right to keep the font the same size in the sub-menus as the parent menu but I need different sizes for each so the answer above from @hungerstar was more accurate, but thank you. The Issue #2 answer is spot on! That was what I was looking for. Couldn't see it. Thank you again. As for Issue #3, the question was regarding keeping the links active with a set background for the active page I was on. Your suggestion is already in the script I uploaded. As your Issue #2 answer only, and I can only tick one, I have to mark the answer to hungerstar. Sorry, but thank you.